# Convergence of stochastic integral to Brownian motion

Tags: convergence-divergence, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $a \in \mathbb R$, $W(t)$ a standard Brownian motion, and

$$ V(t) = a \int_0^{t} e^{-a(t-s)} d W_s. $$

Is it true that
$$ \int_0^t V(u) \, du = W(t) - W(0) \quad \text{as} \quad a \to \infty $$
in a certain sense?

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Comment: Hint: for all Itô-integrable functions $f(t, \omega) = g(t)$ (that is, for non-random integrands), $\int_0^t g(s)\mathrm{d}B_s$ follows the normal distribution with zero mean and variance which can be computed using the Itô isometry.

Comment: Ah yeah, that is reminiscent of a course I took some years ago. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis The convergence which is asked for, is stronger than convergence in distribution.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Would you know whether the resulting Brownian motion is the same as the Brownian motion we started with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
\begin{align}
\int_0^t V_u du
& = \int_0^t\int_0^t 1_{s\le u}ae^{-a(u-s)}dW_sdu\\
& = \int_0^t\int_0^t 1_{s\le u}ae^{-a(u-s)}dudW_s,\quad\text{stochastic Fubini}.
\end{align}
Thus (assuming $W_0=0$ for simplicity),
\begin{align}
E\left[\left(\int_0^t V_u du-W_t\right)^2\right]
& = \int_0^t\left(
\int_0^t 1_{s\le u}ae^{-a(u-s)}du-1
\right)^2 ds,\quad\text{Ito isometry},\\
& = \frac{1}{2a}(1-e^{-2at})\rightarrow 0\text{ as }a\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
That is, 
$$\int_0^tV_udu\rightarrow W_t\text{ in }L^2\text{ for each }t>0.$$
In fact, $\{X^n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$, $X^n_t:=\int_0^t n\int_0^u e^{-n(u-s)}dW_sdu$, converges uniformly to $W$ on compact intervals.